# Songsmiths and dictators

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, language, history

> Russian to infamous Soviet dictator.
>   Spanish to liquefied timepiece creator.
>   English to songsmith with capital name.
>   French to one whose end in Waterloo came.

What are we listing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Foreign language or, maybe, not their mother's tongue

Russian to infamous Soviet dictator.

> Josef Stalin was Georgian, so Russian is not his first language

Spanish to liquefied timepiece creator.

> Dali, author of the liquefied clocks was Catalan, again Spanish is not his first language

English to songsmith with capital name, courtesy of @MOehm

> Irving Berlin, composer (born Israel Berlin (Russian: Израиль Моисеевич Бейлин)), mother tongue Russian, but lived in USA

French to one whose end in Waterloo came.

> Napoleon, who lost the battle at Waterloo, was born on the island of Corsica to an Italian family, so again French was not his first language.

Comment: I had thought about this, too, but I'm not so super convinced that it fits the Spanish creator. The pattern does fit [this songsmith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irving_Berlin), though.

Comment: @jafe Am I anywhere near?

Comment: @rhsquared yup, just fill in the missing one :)

Comment: You get the tick! (The third one's first language was Yiddish, not Russian, though)

Answer (score 4):

There’s a

> Language tag, which makes me think of something to do with translations....

So a partial answer follows:

Russian to infamous Soviet dictator.

> As identified by @AHKieran, this is Josef Stalin. Stalin is a Russian word meaning STEEL.

Spanish to liquefied timepiece creator.

> This is painter Salvador Dalí. Although Dalí doesn’t have a Spanish translation I don’t think, Salvador does, and it’s SAVIOUR.

English to songsmith with capital name.

> Not sure, but if their last name is a capital city I’d imagine it would also be a METROPOLIS.

French to one whose end in Waterloo came.

> As identified by @AHKieran, this is Napoléon Bonaparte. As a Corsican, Bonaparte has a French/Italian/Corsican translation of GOOD SOLUTION or GOOD MATCH.

Putting all these together, and coming up with a solution undoubtedly far from @jafe’s intended one, we have

> Steel, Saviour, Metropolis, Good Solution.

That can only lead us to

> SUPERMAN.

Comment: Ah translations makes more sense. I thought the named languages was a bit obvious

Comment: This is not the intended answer, but... wow. Very nice fit to all the clues.

Answer (score 2):

Are you listing:

> Languages and famous people who spoke them?

*Russian to infamous Soviet dictator*

> Josef Stalin

*Spanish to liquefied timepiece creator*

> Not sure

*English to songsmith with capital name*

> Paris Hilton???

*French to one whose end in Waterloo came*

> Napoleon Bonaparte

Comment: You have almost the right idea :)